# Как развернуть приложения google-apps-script для всех, включая анонимных пользователей

Tags: google-apps-script

Я создал код в Google-apps-script и развернул его для всех, включая анонимных пользователей. 
Сейчас анонимные пользователи могут выполнять скрипт при заходе по ссылке 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbytS6t1N1EW-OJhHDZMAvzE8WCJZf/exec

Этот скрипт обрабатывает POST-запрос и удаленный API сервис отсылает данные на этот скрипт, но добавляет к адресу /events/all:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbytS6t1N1EW-OJhHDZMAvzE8WCJZf/exec/events/all 
а по этому пути анонимные пользователи не могут открыть и выполнить скрипт (при заходе по последней ссылке, перекидывает на страницу авторизации google и при успешной авторизации, скрипт выполняется).

Не могу понять, можно ли открыть скрипт по пути https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbytS6t1N1EW-OJhHDZMAvzE8WCJZf/exec/events/all для всех пользователей?

Или может как то ещё можно обработать POST-запрос?

Answer (score 0):

У вашего сервиса может быть только один эндпоинт, который заканчивается на `/exec`. Проектируйте API с учетом этой особенности.

GET

`/exec?target=events&range=all`

POST

`/exec`

```
{
  data: {
    events: all
  }
}
```